Test if pointer to AWS Golang SDK struct is null/exits
Using this code:
 for _, region := range availableRegions.Regions {
        fmt.Println("Region Name :", *region.RegionName)

        ec2Client := ec2.NewFromConfig(cfg, func(o *ec2.Options) {
            o.Region = (*region.RegionName)
        })

        describeIntefacesPaginator := ec2.NewDescribeNetworkInterfacesPaginator(ec2Client, &ec2.DescribeNetworkInterfacesInput{}, func(o *ec2.DescribeNetworkInterfacesPaginatorOptions) {
            o.Limit = 1000
        })

        for describeIntefacesPaginator.HasMorePages() {
            output, err := describeIntefacesPaginator.NextPage(context.TODO())
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error", err)
                break
            }

            for _, netInterface := range output.NetworkInterfaces {
               fmt.Println(*netInterface.NetworkInterfaceId, "-", *netInterface.Association)
            }

I am trying to test whether *netInterface.Association is null/exists in the struct using:
if netInterface.Association != nil {
   fmt.Println(*netInterface.Association.PublicIp)

}

If I convert netInterface.Association to JSON and print it out it will show "Association":null. From the posting here using:
if *netInterface.Association != nil
Is flagged by the compiler as a mismatched type which looks like it is because Association is of type *NetworkInterfaceAssociation and:
if netInterface.Association != nil
Will compile but will cause an invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference error. If I could create an empty NetworkInterface struct I could possibly do this but it doesn't look like I am able to.
Network interface eni-0b11eac272db77223 has an association as an Elastic IP is attached to it but eni-0c03afbd1d2638e74 doesn't:
$ aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --network-interface-ids eni-0b11eac272db77223 --query NetworkInterfaces[*].Association --region ap-south-1
[
    {
        "AllocationId": "eipalloc-06d32a25e5aa78d41",
        "AssociationId": "eipassoc-0792a3966480e6fc4",
        "IpOwnerId": "<redacted>",
        "PublicDnsName": "ec2-3-108-73-222.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
        "PublicIp": "3.108.73.222"
    }
    
    
$ aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --network-interface-ids eni-0c03afbd1d2638e74 --query NetworkInterfaces[*].Association --region ap-south-1
[]

$ aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --network-interface-ids eni-0c03afbd1d2638e74 --query NetworkInterfaces[0].Association --region ap-south-1
null

$ aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --network-interface-ids eni-0c03afbd1d2638e74 --query NetworkInterfaces[0] --region ap-south-1
{
    "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1c",
    "Description": "test",
    "Groups": [
        {
            "GroupName": "default",
            "GroupId": "sg-0242772b747b89a45"
        }
    ],
    "InterfaceType": "interface",
    "Ipv6Addresses": [],
    "MacAddress": "06:22:17:0b:8b:d3",
    "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-0c03afbd1d2638e74",
    "OwnerId": "<redacted>",
    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-24-26.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
    "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.24.26",
    "PrivateIpAddresses": [
        {
            "Primary": true,
            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-24-26.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.24.26"
        }
    ],
    "RequesterId": "<redacted>",
    "RequesterManaged": false,
    "SourceDestCheck": true,
    "Status": "available",
    "SubnetId": "subnet-09e693c955f141ea7",
    "TagSet": [],
    "VpcId": "vpc-0e9a0e28dad668f8a"
}

The program will print out eni-0b11eac272db77223, the address information of the pointer and the Elastic IP but then segfault when it tries to get the details on the other interface:
$ ./findip
Region Name : ap-south-1
eni-0b11eac272db77223 - {0xc0000a0660 0xc0000a0670 <nil> <nil> 0xc0000a0650 0xc0000a0640 0xc0000a0630 {}}
3.108.73.222
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x73c27b]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()


Are you sure the invalid memory address error comes from the line if netInterface.Association == nil? That can only happen if netInterface is nil.

@Burak Serdar
Yes. I have added the output to my question. Only Association is nil

That stack dump does not show line number information. Show the code that fails. When it fails, the stack dump should have line number information.

@Burak Serdar - Looked at the line and found that the segfault was on the line where I was printing *netInterface.Association after getting the details on the network interface. If Association is null then that will cause a segfault. Thank you for your help.
